# Why am I unable to boot from Linux Mint after adding its boot sector manually to the MBR via BCDEdit?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, linux-mint, mbr

I'm trying to dual boot Windows and Linux Mint without modifying the Windows' MBR (contrary to the default setup of a Linux installation). For that, I've installed both the Linux OS and its bootloader in a separate partition (formatted in ext4 format). After that, I've booted from the Linux installation pen drive and used the following command to copy the first 512 bytes of the Linux partition:
`dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/home/mint.bin bs=512 count=1`
sda4 was the partition where I've installed Mint.

After copying the .bin files to the Windows root directory, I booted from Windows and opened Command Prompt with administrative privileges to add an entry into the MBR table, via the following set of commands:

```
bcdedit /create /d "Mint" /application osloader
bcdedit /set {ID} device partition=c:
bcdedit /set {ID}  path \mint.bin
bcdedit /displayorder {ID} /addlast
```

The {ID} was generated after the first command, which I copied and pasted in relevant places.

The entry for Mint is created as expected, but upon loading from it, Mint fails to load with an error similar to this:
https://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Windows-not-booting-1-640x356.png

The installation itself is valid because if I use EasyBCD to create an entry, it works successfully. This leaves me wondering about my mistake. I have no idea what I've done wrong, so any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. I'm including the .bin and .mbr files I made in Mint as well:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FQ5jMKjMkJ3_M5gab_7NOBtO78o7VM0/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fujj-_JC72gsxP0jiaVkhC7LcQaN8nVH/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cLdSFL-hIvdx9pvk153VnumM9Ilf2r5a/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNbANvTwARApnWTdm3MmtNlyTj7UgPZr/view?usp=sharing

Please note that `mint.bin` is of 512 bytes, and `mint2.bin` is of 440 bytes. That was something I did on a whim but to no avail.
P.S.: I created .mbr files because I noticed that the file path for an EasyBCD-created entry had a file with an extension .mbr.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run **`dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/home/mint.bin bs=512 count=1`** this command exactly after linux installation has finished **without any reboots**.

If installing ubuntu , once you have finished installing , click on

continue testing, mount the target drive and then make the copy of the sectors.

Refer my answer here : https://superuser.com/a/1603062/777184

Feel free to upvote the answers/accept it if it helped :)